# How can I fire an event in WinJS (equivalent of .trigger("") in jQuery)

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

I would like to know how can I fire an event from code. In jQuery to fire a "onchange" event you would simply $("selector").trigger("change"). Is there a way to do the same using WinJS.

[All suggestions of including jQuery will be discarded]

Thanks.

Comment: Why is it that you want a "WinJS" version of trigger instead of a JavaScript one? (If you were in some environment where libs aren't available what will you do?) Relying purely on libraries is **terrible terrible** practice and you should know lots of vanilla JS before even trying libs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fireEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is probably what you want.

> Fires a specified event on the object.

Given that markup

```html
<p>
    <button 
        id="oButton" 
        onclick="this.innerText='I have been clicked!'">Button
    </button>
</p>
```

You can do

```js
oButton.fireEvent("onclick");
```

Comment: Thanks! That will do the trick. I was using it the wrong way, I was typing "change" instead of "onchange"

Answer (score 0):

In your ready function:

```
WinJS.Utilities.query("#yourSelector").listen("change", this.customClicked, false)
```

And then define customClicked function  (can be named anything)

```
customClicked: function(eventInfo){
   <!--do stuff -->
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.initUIEvent`:

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var еvent = document.createEvent("UIEvents");
еvent .initUIEvent("click", false, false, window, 1);
button.dispatchEvent(еvent );
```

More info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.initUIEvent)

Answer (score 0):

To fire and respond to a custom event do this.

fire the event

```
WinJS.Application.queueEvent({type: 'ev_login_completed'})
```

to respond to the custom event

```
WinJS.Application.addEventListener('ev_login_completed', function (e) {
             // do stuff  })
```

HTH